# Can Pylint be configured to color Fixme warnings differently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, ansi-escape, pylintrc

I would like my fixme messages to be blue, instead of purple, to differentiate them from other purple messages.

Does Pylint even have colorization options? I can't find any.

I see these things called "formatters", but that sounds more complex than what I need.

(I'd probably write a postprocessing script that changes the ANSI codes on the fly before I'd bother with a formatter, because the latter is more likely for personal reuse.  I'd rather avoid anything and just slip a nice option into .plintrc)

[image: example of fixme messages colorized in purple]

I tried looking through the documentation, google search, and ChatGPT, but didn't seem to find a suitable option.

Answer (score 1):

Pylint has [a colored text reporter](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/blob/c5f3ff4c37a2b5f50e6bca2529f9290f8a58f592/pylint/reporters/text.py#L207-L255) that you could base your own reporter on. The way to use it is the following; see [output options](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/usage/output.html#output-options): `pylint --output-format=json:somefile.json,colorized`.

[You will need to register your custom reporter to be able to use it](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/blob/c5f3ff4c37a2b5f50e6bca2529f9290f8a58f592/pylint/reporters/text.py#L259)

Comment: Thanks!  That doesn't quite tell me enough to make it happen, but that gets me a lot closer. Don't suppose you would know how to write the reporter in mind?  Say I just wanted 'fixmes' to be blue instead, without anything else being changed, how would I do that?

Comment: In `def handle_message(self, msg: Message) -> None:` check what is in the ``msg`` variable and treat fixmes differently than the other messages.

Comment: Clever, Pierre, but at that point, it would be easier for me to postprocess my results with sed and change the ansi color code otherwise i'm essentilally creating a personal fork of pylint